# Can't catch the lower link set in pure CSS horizontal menu (horizontal link set under horizontal text tabs)?

Tags: css, menu, menuitem

I want to create a pure CSS on hover horizontal menu.

I partially achieved what I want in http://jsfiddle.net/dq8z192L/11/

As you'll see ı aimed a on-hover menu. Horizontal tabs and each tabs gives birth to a horizontal set of links below.

Then I created http://jsfiddle.net/dq8z192L/13/ . Aim was: let the most left tab's link set appears at default and let the other tabs' link set works on hover.

However my problem with CSS2 below is I can't catch set of links with mouse during hovering HEADING 02 or HEADING 03 tabs despite the fact that both CSS1 and CSS2 has `.linkgroup2:hover , .linkgroup3:hover { display:block; }` line.

I couldn't understand the reason

What am I doing wrong? Can you please correct me?

*NOTE: HTML codes are same for 2 cases.*

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="c1">HEADING 01</div>
    <div id="c2">HEADING 02</div>
    <div id="c3">HEADING 03</div>
    <ul class="linkgroup1">
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 03</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="linkgroup2">
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 04</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 05</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 06</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="linkgroup3">
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 07</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 08</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 09</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div><p>some stuff here ...</p></div>
```

**CSS 1 (aim is partially achieved with this CSS)**

```
#c1, #c3 { width: 33%; float:left; background-color:#ef6;}
#c2 { width: 34%; float:left; background-color:#eee; }
ul { list-style:none; }
li { display: inline; }

.linkgroup1 , .linkgroup2 , .linkgroup3 { display:none; }

#c1:hover ~ .linkgroup1 { display:block; }

#c2:hover ~ .linkgroup2 { display:block; }
#c2:hover ~ .linkgroup1 { display:none; }
#c2:hover ~ .linkgroup3 { display:none; }

#c3:hover ~ .linkgroup3 { display:block; }
#c3:hover ~ .linkgroup1 { display:none; }
#c3:hover ~ .linkgroup2 { display:none; }

.linkgroup1, .linkgroup2 , .linkgroup3 { padding-top:3em; }
.linkgroup1:hover , .linkgroup2:hover , .linkgroup3:hover { display:block; }

.linkgroup1 { background-color:#6e7fe4; }
.linkgroup2 { background-color:#f4e32b; }
.linkgroup3 { background-color:#b3ffff; }
```

**CSS 2 (this CSS doesn't work at all)**

```
#c1, #c3 { width: 33%; float:left; background-color:#ef6;}
#c2 { width: 34%; float:left; background-color:#eee; }
ul { list-style:none; }
li { display: inline; }

.linkgroup2 , .linkgroup3 { display:none; }

#c2:hover ~ .linkgroup1 { display:none; }
#c2:hover ~ .linkgroup3 { display:none; }
#c2:hover ~ .linkgroup2 { display:block; }

#c3:hover ~ .linkgroup1 { display:none; }
#c3:hover ~ .linkgroup2 { display:none; }
#c3:hover ~ .linkgroup3 { display:block; }

.linkgroup1, .linkgroup2 , .linkgroup3 { padding-top:3em; }
.linkgroup2:hover , .linkgroup3:hover { display:block; }

.linkgroup1 { background-color:#6e7fe4; }
.linkgroup2 { background-color:#f4e32b; }
.linkgroup3 { background-color:#b3ffff; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing any of your html structure you can only solve this with absolute positioning of your `<ul>`s to fix the `z-index` by taking your elements out of the flow, because your first `.linkgroup1` will always be getting in the way between your links and other uls and will ruin the `:hover`

Relevant parts:

```
/* adjust the wrapping div height since you need to account for the ul height which will belost dues to the needed position:absolute - you could name your wrapping div .menu to make it clear */
body > div {position:relative;height:60px;}

/* absolutely position your ul so it's taken out of the flow */
ul { 
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/* increase the z-index of the second and third menu so :hover will always be above the first one leaving it below when second is hovered and first still visible */
.linkgroup2, .linkgroup3 { display:none;z-index:2; }
```

**Live sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/mkwjvdz8/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that I've created of what you want: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq8z192L/57/). Basically what's happening in your second jsFiddle is that when the cursor leaves the area of `#c2` or `#c3` to move on to the area of `linkgroup2` or `linkgroup3`, the `linkgroup1` element starts appearing again and the CSS which you had added to come in action when the cursor is over `#c2` or `#c3`doesn't work anymore since the cursor is now over the area of the `linkgroup1` element.

Here's the new code which I've used in my fiddle.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="c1">HEADING 01</div>
        <ul class="linkgroup1">
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 01</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 02</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 03</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="c2">HEADING 02</div>
        <ul class="linkgroup2">
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 04</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 05</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 06</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="c3">HEADING 03</div>
        <ul class="linkgroup3">
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 07</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 08</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 09</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">link 10</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <p>some stuff here ...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#c1, #c3 {
    background-color:#ef6;
}
#c2 {
    background-color:#eee;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul li ul {
    width: 95%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li:first-child ul {
    display: block;
}
.linkgroup1, .linkgroup2, .linkgroup3 {
    padding-top:3em;
}
.linkgroup1 {
    background-color:#6e7fe4;
}
.linkgroup2 {
    background-color:#f4e32b;
}
.linkgroup3 {
    background-color:#b3ffff;
}
```

Comment: He needs to use the same html.